# ASP.NET mouseclick event from panel not working

Tags: html, asp.net, .net

I want an event to fire when I click the top panel on my ASP.NET page.

I put a button over the panel, but it's displayed as a small gray button instead of stretching to cover the panel.  If I press it, the event fires ok.  But then THE BUTTON DISAPPEARS.

I need button to be invisible, cover the entire panel, refresh page when clicked, and be there after page refreshed.

Here's what the little button looks like...

[image]

Here's my code:

```
        btn-panel{
            position: fixed;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            opacity: 0;
            z-index: -1;
        }
        </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!---------------   D B G   M E S S A G E S   ------------------>
        <asp:Panel ID="DBG_PANEL" runat="server" Visible="False">
            <asp:Label ID="DBG" runat="server" Text="DEBUG DATA"  ></asp:Label>
       </asp:Panel>

    <form id="HOME_FORM" runat="server" style="border-style: none;" title="">
        <table id="TABLE1" cellspacing="10">
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" align="left" class="style5">
                    <asp:Panel ID="PAGE_TITLE_PANEL" runat="server" BorderStyle="Outset" 
                                             BackColor="#E1FFFF" Width="600px">
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <asp:Label ID="PROGRAM_TITLE_LABEL" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" 
                        Font-Size="X-Large" Text="title" Font-Names="Arial"></asp:Label>
                        <br />
                        <span class="style20">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<em>&nbsp; - Online community -- <br /> </em></span>
                        <asp:Button ID="Button_title_bar" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="btn-panel" OnClick="Button_title_bar_Click" />
                    </asp:Panel>




' User clicked title bar, so re-init web.
Sub Button_title_bar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_title_bar.Click
    response.Redirect( PROGRAM_WEB_ADDRESS )
End Sub
```

Comment: Look like no modifier, Public Sub Button_title_bar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) not sure though

Answer (score 0):

You could do this work around to achieve what you are trying to do. You can set the Visible attribute on your button to `Visible="False"`. Then you could wire up a javascript click event on the Panel that would fire the click event for your button. This would essentially make your Panel clickable like having the button invisible and covering the panel.

Try adding in an HTML `<script>` block like this:

```
<script>
    var panelId = '<%= PAGE_TITLE_PANEL.ClientID %>';
    var buttonId = '<%= Button_title_bar.ClientID %>';

    document.getElementById(panelId).onclick = function(){
        document.getElementById(buttonId).click();
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Done.  But nothing happens: no page event, no button event.